# Create a 2D array from a 1D array

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

As said in the title, I have a function "load" that returns returns a structure which contains 2 int and an array of characters. This array is on 1D, and looks like : [################  ### $  $  ### #  .# ###  . #.@ ###$# *   ###  ###############]
And I would like to print it as :

```
##########
######  ##
# $  $  ##
# #  .# ##
#  . #.@ #
##$# *   #
##  ######
##########
```

knowing that the width is here 10. 
So my question is how to, every 10 characters, manage to go back to the next line...?
Here is what I've written so far :

```
void print_map(map map_loaded){
    char *p=map_loaded.p_char;
    int height=map_loaded.height;
    for(int i=0; i<height; i++){
            printf("%c", *p[i]);
        }
```

As you can see, I just know how to read every character, but I have no clue about how to go back to line...
I would really appreciate if someone could read my code and give me his/her feedback... Thanks in advance !

Comment: You should show how your `map` struct is defined, and explain what the fields mean. For example: Is `map_loaded.height` the number of rows in the printed grid? Is `map_loaded.p_char` null-terminated? What other data members are in the `map` struct?

Comment: Print '\n' for newline.

Comment: **`*p[i]` is bad!** either way you look at it ... `*p` has type `char`; you cannot index a char ... `p[i]` has type `char`; you cannot dereference a char.

Comment: @pmg can you elaborate on what the problem is with dereferencing a char. I haven't heard of that being an issue before.

Comment: @Patrick: do you think `*(42)` (dereference the integer 42) is legal? What about `*("foo")` (dereference a (string converted to a) pointer)? Or `*("foo"[2])` (dereference a char)?

Comment: Ah, I think I was misunderstanding what it was doing, you definitely do not want to go to memory location b in any circumstance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As all you need is a new line after every 10 characters, just check if you have printed 10 characters since last adition of new line.

```
void print_map(map map_loaded){
char *p=map_loaded.p_char; 
int height=map_loaded.height; 
for(int i=0; i<height; i++){ 
printf("%c", p[i]);

if( (i+1)%10==0)
printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: **`*p[i]` is bad!** either way you look at it ... `*p` has type `char`; you cannot index a char ... `p[i]` has type `char`; you cannot dereference a char.